# Is this possible to change script path in index.html file after build completed?

Tags: angular-cli, angular-cli-v7

I have one angular-cli application, when i give **ng build** command it creates build file which has index.html file.

In index.html file, scripts paths are referred like below:

```html
<script type="text/javascript" **src="runtime.js"**></script>
<script type="text/javascript" **src="polyfills.js"**></script>
<script type="text/javascript" **src="styles.js"**></script>
<script type="text/javascript" **src="vendor.js"**></script>
<script type="text/javascript" **src="main.js"**></script>
```

But i want to change that script like below,

```html
<script type="text/javascript" **src="~/runtime.js"**></script>
<script type="text/javascript" **src="~/polyfills.js"**></script>
<script type="text/javascript" **src="~/styles.js"**></script>
<script type="text/javascript" **src="~/vendor.js"**></script>
<script type="text/javascript" **src="~/main.js"**></script>
```

Is it possible to change the path without using find and replace method?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have found answer for my question in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45328256/modify-the-src-location-for-javascript-script-tags-during-ng-build).

Please check here

**"deployUrl": "/app/",** this property helps me to achieve my requirement

Update, 2023 / Angular 16: `"deployUrl"` has been replaced by `"baseHref"`. This property is added **angular.json** inside of architect/build/options